# Make DateString[do,"ISODate"] also Work on Version 10

Tags: date-and-time

In Version 11, new types of output elements were introduced: "ISODate" and "ISOTimeDate".

In order to aalso use them on Version 10, I put these lines to `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]`:

```
Unprotect[DateString]; 
DateString["ISODate"] := 
  DateString[{"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}];    (* 1 *)
DateString[do_DateObject,"ISODate"] := 
  DateString[do,{"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]; (* 2 does not work! *)
DateString["ISODateTime"] := 
  DateString[{"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "T", "Hour24", ":", 
    "Minute", ":", "Second"}];                       (* 3 *)
DateString[do_DateObject,"ISODate"] := DateString[do, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "T", "Hour24", ":",      
    "Minute", ":", "Second"}];                       (* 4 does not work! *)
Protect[DateString];
```

1. `DateString["ISODate"]` works, it returns e.g. `"2016-11-12"`.
2. `DateString[DateObject[Date[]], "ISODate"]` does not work, it returns `"ISODate"` - although `Head[DateObject[Date[]]]` is `DateObject`. **Why?**
3. `DateString["ISODateTime"]` works, it returns e.g. `"2016-11-12T19:17:37"`.
4. `DateString[DateObject[Date[]], "ISOTimeDate"]` does not work, it returns `"ISOTimeDate"`. **Why?**

One could of course write `DateString[DateObject[Date[]], {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}` to get the ISODate, but I took the challenge to use the keyword string `"ISODate"` to make a definition for it.

Comment: Just for completeness: `DateString["ISODate"]` seems to work since at least version 10.3, which version are you using?

Comment: $Version returns 10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)

Comment: Have you considered adding an `isoDateFormat = {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"};` and `isoDateTimeFormat = 
 Join[isoDateFormat, {"T", "Hour24", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}];` to *init.m* instead of unprotecting a built-in function.  Then `DateString[isoDateFormat]`,  `DateString[isoDateTimeFormat]`, and other variants would do the job without issues.

Comment: I believe you are having issues because your patterns are defined after the build-in patterns so the built-in patterns match first.  `DateString[do_DateObject, "ISODate"]` matches the built-in pattern `DateString[_DateObject, _String]`.  Since this pattern is defined before your `"ISODate"` pattern it executes first and returns `"ISODate"` because that format is undefined in version 10.1.0. I don't think you can force your pattern to appear before the built-in patterns.  If that is the case then see my suggestion in my above comment.

Comment: Edmund, that's a good explanation. And you already pointed a way around it. - I remember to have seen something using Block where someone influenced the order of definitions later, but I can't figure it out any more.

Comment: I think you should put the version information into your question so people don't wonder when they get different results than you claim with later 10.x versions. As for the `Block` method you remember I am pretty sure that is for reordering normal patterns and wouldn't work for internal patterns, but I might be wrong with that. I also think you should try to find a solution which doesn't need to unprotect and redefine system symbols...